# Tslint exclude doesn't work correctly, React-Dropzone

Tags: json, config, tslint, react-dropzone

I have the following structure:

```
components
  my_component
    tslint.json
tslint.json
```

root tslint.json

```
{
  "extends": ["...some/tslint.json"],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "components/**/node_modules/**/",
      "components/**/node_modules/*",
      "components/*/node_modules/",
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

component tslint.json

```
{
  "extends": ["../../tslint.json"],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I run `"lint": "tslint \"components/**/**.ts*\""`
from the root, I get these errors:

```
ERROR: components/my_component/node_modules/react-dropzone/typings/tests/accept.tsx[78, 22]: ' should be "
ERROR: components/my_component/node_modules/react-dropzone/typings/tests/accept.tsx[78, 36]: ' should be "
...
```

It should've work even without local tslint.json
But I tried to override, and even this didn't help

How to make it work?